# Creating a drawable rectangle in xml with one gradient on the top half and another on the bottom half

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a drawable in xml, a rectangle with one gradient on the top half, and another on the bottom half.  This is NOT the way to do it, apparently:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <gradient
                        android:startColor="#5a5a5a88"
                        android:endColor="#14141488"
                        android:angle="270" android:centerX="0.25"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:top="80px">
                <gradient
                        android:startColor="#5aff5a88"
                        android:endColor="#14ff1488"
                        android:angle="270" android:centerX="0.25"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

How can I do this, preferably in a way that makes it stretchable to any height?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your goal is to have a gradient with a central color (starts at color A, transitions to B in the middle, then transitions to C at the end), add `android:centerColor` and `android:centerY` attributes to one of your `<shape>` elements and nuke the other. You can do the three-color gradient all in a single shape.

Comment: Actually, I want two different areas of color... so, it wouldn't really be transitioning to another color at the end.  

In the middle, it would start with an entirely different color and transition to another color at the end.

Comment: Then why do you need it all in one `Drawable`? `<layer-list>` is not a `LinearLayout` -- they don't vertically stack.

Comment: I need it all in one Drawable because I want to use it as the background for a LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

small bug for you, top attribute should be in item element ;)

it work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
       <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#5a5a5a88"
                    android:endColor="#14141488"
                    android:angle="270" android:centerX="0.25"/>

       </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="80dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#5aff5a88"
                    android:endColor="#14ff1488"
                    android:angle="270" android:centerX="0.25"/>

    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```